# Full calendar change Icon to hand on hover on an uneditable event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

how do we this in full calendar?

where the form wont be editable/draggable the cursor becomes a hand upon hovering on an event?

I've tried overriding the css but it doesn't work

Comment: I'm fairly sure the elements gain a class when they are non-editable. You should be able to apply more specific CSS styles against that

Comment: I actually I did this 

`.fc-event-container:hover {
    cursor: hand!important;
}`

still won't be overriden

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @Stalinko I've solved this. turns out `cursor:hand` doesn't work but `cursor:pointer` does

Answer (score 0):

Old subject, but found the way:

set event as

```
editable:false,
```

then add

```
eventRender: function(info) {
    if(!info.event.startEditable) {
        $(info.el).css('cursor','not-allowed');
        return;
    }
}
```